# Create a list of attribute of nested nodes from XML file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

I have an XML file as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<files>
    <file name="1">
        <file name="4">     
        </file> 
    </file>
    <file name="2">
    </file>
    <file name="3">
        <file name="5">
            <file name="7">
            </file>
        </file>
    </file>
</files>
```

Now I want to create a list of strings/numbers which save all the attribute `name` in a list/array which has the nested nodes hierarchy in it. For example for the above XML file the expected list would be,

```
(1,4
2
3,5,7)
```

Because I could could know the desired node in which level is.

Would you please let me know what is your idea about having such a list?

**Update:** After [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s answer, If the children nodes are in the same hierarchy, then would in the following way.

The XML file:

```
<files>
<file name="1">
    <file name="4"/>     
    <file name="2">
      <file name="3"/>
    </file> 
</file>
<file name="5"/>
```

and the desired output:

```
1,4
1,2
1,2,3
5
```

*PS. After testing for some examples I noticed that I have to have first parent and then children in case when there are two or more children from the same level.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you possibly want:

- For all `file` elements which don't have a *child* `file` element
- Work out the `file` element ancestry
- Take the `name` attribute for each ancestor, and join it together

So I *think* this should work, creating an `IEnumerable<List<int>>`:

```
var hierarchy = doc.Descendants("file")
                   .Where(x => x.Element("file") == null)
                   .Select(x => x.AncestorsAndSelf("file")
                                 .Reverse()
                                 .Select(f => (int) f.Attribute("name"))
                                 .ToList());
```

Complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var hierarchy = doc.Descendants("file")
                   .Where(x => x.Element("file") == null)
                   .Select(x => x.AncestorsAndSelf("file")
                                 .Reverse()
                                 .Select(f => (int) f.Attribute("name"))
                                 .ToList());

        foreach (var item in hierarchy)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", item));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1, 4
2
3, 5, 7
```

An alternative approach is to take all top-level `file` elements, and for each one, find all the descendants:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var hierarchy = doc.Root.Elements("file")
                   .Select(x => x.DescendantsAndSelf("file")
                                 .Select(f => (int) f.Attribute("name"))
                                 .ToList());

        foreach (var item in hierarchy)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", item));
        }
    }
}
```

Now both of those give the same result at the moment, because you've basically got a "line" from each top-level `file` element. However, you should consider what you want the result to be if you had XML like this:

```
<files>
    <file name="1">
        <file name="4"/>     
        <file name="2">
          <file name="3"/>
        </file> 
    </file>
    <file name="5"/>
</files>
```

Here the top-level element with name 1 has two children - what would you want the result to be?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. What do you mean with the XML file?

Comment: @SaberJalilzadeh: Whoops, sorry, hadn't indented that bit of the answer. Have another look :)

Comment: Well, very nice question. For this type XML file the result would be as
1,4-
1,2,3-
5 .

Comment: The way you solved the problem using `AncestorsAndSelf` is excellent! and is the best fit for sapmle xml you provided.

Comment: Very keen answer for XML file and the case you described!! Really appreciate. :)

Comment: @JonSkeet, Just there is problem. The problem is that for the XML file that you've mentioned. It skips the parent to print out. For example in the XML file you wrote it skips the element `1,2` before `1,2,3`. May I ask how I could solve it?

Comment: @SaberJalilzadeh: Sorry, hadn't seen this comment before. The first solution should still work... will give it a try.

Comment: @SaberJalilzadeh: The first piece of code running against the last XML file gives me exactly what you said you wanted... (1, 4), (1, 2, 3), (5)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your comment, But I understood that the output should be as: `(1,4), (1,2), (1,2,3), (5)`. in the answer it is skipping `(1,2)`.

Comment: @SaberJalilzadeh: Well that's not what you said before. You wrote: "For this type XML file the result would be as 1,4- 1,2,3- 5". Why would it output "1,2"? If it's going to include paths for non-terminal nodes, why aren't there also elements for just "1" and "5"? Basically, you need to make requirements *crystal clear*.

Comment: Right, But in the treeview form that I noticed it is skipping one node. Sorry!!

Comment: @SaberJalilzadeh: What treeview? Sorry, you're still being very unclear. I cannot help you with requirements that aren't expressed clearly.

Comment: In the original XML file. I am afraid could not afford the original file due to security. But my question is that it is skipping the parent. Why? and how I could solve it? Many thanks.

Comment: @SaberJalilzadeh: This is now even *less* clear - the original file would never show "1, 2" as "2" isn't even a child node of "1". At this point I think you should really take a step back and think about what requirement you think my code is missing - because my output matches what you've written in the question *precisely*. (If you've discovered that your requirements are actually different, you should post a *new* question with those different requirements. But we can't be expected to guess them.)

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the hierarchy using [`XElement.DescendantsAndSelf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendantsandself(v=vs.110).aspx). For example:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(@"d:\xml.xml");
var list = document.Root.Elements()
                   .Select(x=>string.Join(",", 
                       x.DescendantsAndSelf().Select(d=>d.Attribute("name").Value)))
                   .ToList();
```

The result of above sample is of type `List<string>` which each element contains comma separated names in hierarchy. If you need each element contain `IEnumerable<string>` of hierarchy for more flexibility, remove `string.Join` from select statement.

**EDIT**
The answer is posted based on your original post which each file has only one file as child. If you have more than one file as child of a file, you should solve the problem using [`AncestorsAndSelf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346865(v=vs.110).aspx) as described in Jon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36149478/3110834).

Comment: The answer is posted based on your original post which each file has only one file as child. If you have more than one file as child of a file, you should solve the problem using [`AncestorsAndSelf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346865(v=vs.110).aspx) as described in Jon's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36149478/3110834).